# Codename One L10NManager.getInstance().formatDateLongStyle on iPhone

Tags: codenameone

On a Codename One app, I have this code:

`L10NManager.getInstance().formatDateLongStyle(myDate)`

The problem is that the resulting string is localized correctly in Italian on the Codename One Simulator and on my Android smartphone (for example `7 novembre 1981`), while it's always in English on my iPhone (for example `8 Jan 1960` instead of `8 gennaio 1960`).

How can I get the correctly localized string also on iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We delegate this to the native code so I'm guessing this is related to the configuration for date behavior on iOS. Check the localization in settings under `General` -> `Language` -> `Region`.

Comment: In general, language, region, I have "Italiano" as language and "Italia" as region.